# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float'. Simple plot-drawing program

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, typeerror

I'm writing a program that draws [Lennard-Jones potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) with parameters adjusted in GUI with sliders.

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import pylab as p
import math

def show_values():
    V=epsilon.get*(math.exp(-r/sigma.get)-(2/sigma.get)**6)
    p.plot(r,V)
    p.show()


r = p.arange(0.1, 0.2, 0.01)
master = Tk()
epsilon = Scale(master, from_=-10,length=300, to=30, resolution=0.1, width=100)
epsilon.pack()
sigma = Scale(master, from_=-50, to=25,  length=300,resolution=0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL)
sigma.pack()



Button(master, text='Show', command=show_values).pack()
mainloop()
```

But I receive this error message from my IDE (canopy)

```
%run C:/Users/PC/Desktop/lenard.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\lenard.py", line 7, in show_values
    V=epsilon.get*(math.exp(-r/sigma.get)-(2/sigma.get)**6)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'instancemethod'
```

So my question has three parts:

1. What does this message mean?
2. How to make this program work?
3. Is "error message" proper word? How do we call such messages?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding each of your questions:

1. The error message means that you are trying to divide a float object by an instance-method (function) object.
2. Because `get` is an instance-method of the `Scale` class, you must call it as such:

   ```
   V=epsilon.get()*(math.exp(-r/sigma.get())-(2/sigma.get())**6)
   #            ^^                       ^^              ^^
   ```

   Otherwise, you will be performing your calculations with the `get` function object itself.
3. Yes, you may call it that.  The term "traceback" usually refers to the entire error output:

   ```
   Exception in Tkinter callback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
       return self.func(*args)
     File "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\lenard.py", line 7, in show_values
       V=epsilon.get*(math.exp(-r/sigma.get)-(2/sigma.get)**6)
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'instancemethod'
   ```

   while "error message" usually refers to only the last line:

   ```
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'instancemethod'
   ```